# How to rotate a Rect object in Android

Tags: java, android

Ok so i have created a Rectangle on a canvas using this code

```
Rect r =new Rect((point.x - rectWidth / 2), (point.y - rectHeight / 2),(point.x-rectWidth / 2),(point.y + rectHeight / 2));
```

point being the center of the rectangle determined by a touch event. But now I want to be able to rotate this rectangle. Is there any code or method that will allow the user to rotate a shape about its center. I am also interested in getting the corner points of such a rectangle. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use a matrix to rotate a RectF around its center.

Comment: could you tell me how to impose a rectangle on a matrix

Comment: matrix.setRotate(value); matrix.mapRect(r); Then r will have your rotated rectangle

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: this is not a drawable , i'm drawing rect on canvas

Answer (score 8):

To rotate a rectangle around its own center (as opposed to the origin):

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
// point is the point about which to rotate.
m.setRotate(degrees, point.x, point.y);
m.mapRect(r);
```

You can also use `Matrix.mapPoints()` to find how the corners are transformed.

Comment: How would you rotate it around it's center?

Comment: I think it fails to give the desired effect because the data structure Rect is represented only as a horizontal rectangle. The matrix does rotate its constituent points (top left corner and bottom right corner), but the Rect object will remain a horizontal rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Use following:

```
Rect r2 = new Rect(r1);
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.setRotate(-90, r2.centerX(), r2.centerY());
mat.mapRect(r2);
```